# hex search and replace characters with sed linux

Tags: linux, string, sed, replace

I am trying to reformat and condense weather forecast that I get from the National Weather Service and then display it on a section of my conky screen.  To do this I remove the unimportant line feeds and turn the paragraphs into series of sentences, condense the text, and then reformat to the line length needed for display.

The data is in a file testsed.in1.txt and testsed.in2.txt, for simplicity sake we can use the same data for both.  There are no non-ascii characters in the file.  I shortened it to illustrate the problems, normally its quite long and verbose, and that's why I need to condense it.

```
918 PM CST Sun Dec 24 2017~. TONIGHT...Cloudy with ~flurries. Lows 11 to 15. ~.CHRISTMAS DAY...Windy. Flurries and~light snow showers. Temperatures~nearly steady 12 to 16. ~.MONDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy. Lows 1 below to 3 above zero. Wind~chills as low as 10 below zero. Northwest winds 10 to~15 mph. ~.TUESDAY...Mostly sunny. Wind chills as low~as 10 below to 20 below zero. ~.SATURDAY NIGHT...Mostly cloudy. A 30 percent chance of snow in~the evening. ~.SUNDAY...Mostly cloudy. Highs 15 to 19. ~$$~
```

They put ... sequences in the text which I would like to replace with a - dash character.  I don't want the period characters causing problems in the next section of code where I am looking for the important line feeds.  This doesn't work at all and converts the entire file to a series of dashes, except the $~ at the end of the file, not just the sequences of ... three periods in a row.

```
cat testsed.in1.txt | sed -e "s/\x2E\x2E\x2E/\x2D/g" > testsed.out1.txt

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------$~
```

Secondly, I need to find where the important line feeds should go which are \x7E\x2E and convert them to \x07\x2E characters.  This works partially, but it overlays the following character each time.  My reason for doing this is because I really want to convert all the \x7E that are not followed by a \x2E to spaces, and then use tr to convert the \x07 into \x0A line feeds.

```
cat testsed.in2.txt | sed -e "s/\x7E\x2E/\x07\x2E/g" > testsed.out2.txt

918 PM CST Sun Dec 24 2017. TONIGHT...Cloudy with .lurries. Lows 11 to 15. .CHRISTMAS DAY...Windy. Flurries and.ight snow showers. Temperatures.early steady 12 to 16. .MONDAY NIGHT...Partly cloudy. Lows 1 below to 3 above zero. Wind.hills as low as 10 below zero. Northwest winds 10 to.5 mph. .TUESDAY...Mostly sunny. Wind chills as low.s 10 below to 20 below zero. .SATURDAY NIGHT...Mostly cloudy. A 30 percent chance of snow in.he evening. .SUNDAY...Mostly cloudy. Highs 15 to 19. .$~
```

This is my first question here, so I apologize in advance if I made any mistakes. Hopefully someone here is familiar with converting strings under linux and willing to show me how to make it work.

Comment: You're telling us a lot about HOW you want to do something and not enough about WHAT it is you want to do. [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input so we can help you do what you want to do rather than implement however it is you think you should do it. See http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\x2E\x2E\x2E` is the same as `...` which will match any three consecutive characters (the conversion from hex-notation is performed before the regexp is parsed). Since the sample text in `testsed.in1.txt` is 500 characters long, `sed` with convert it to 166 dashes and leave 2 characters untouched (500 = 166*3 + 2).

I would use something like

```
sed -e "s/\.\.\./-/g" testsed.in1.txt > testsed.out1.txt
```

or perhaps

```
sed -e "s/[.]\{3\}/-/g" testsed.in1.txt > testsed.out1.txt
```

The second part of your question suffers from the same problem with `\x2E`.

Comment: That's getting me there.  I didn't know about the period.  I am having the same problem with the $ at the end.  Even \$ didn't match it.  But the soultion you gave fixed the problems, Thanks :)

Comment: @BobC Great! Please consider accepting answer and/or upvote.

Comment: Yes, I did "upvote" your answer, as it did work and answer my question, but I don't see an option to "accept" it.  It said I didn't have 15 posts and therefore my vote wouldn't be included.  I do have a button to answer my own question, but your answer worked.